# How to parse this XML into a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to parse this xml into a hash.  I am using Hash.from_xml, however it doesn't seem to be able to handle cases when the element has a value and other elements as children.  It will only take the value and none of the children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StatusResponse>
    <AccountID>123</AccountID>
    <ErrorMsg />
    <Test>Y</Test>
    <StatusList>
        <PICNumber>
            9477707123456123456781
            <Status>Youritemwasdeliveredat10:09AMon08/06/2007inPALOALTOCA94301.</Status>
            <StatusBreakdown>
                <Status_1>ArrivalatPostOfficeJune02201110:11amNORTHHOLLYWOODCA91605</Status_1>
                <Status_2>ForwardExpiredJune0220116:59amNORTHHOLLYWOODCA</Status_2>
                <Status_3>ProcessedthroughSortFacilityJune0120114:53pmBELLGARDENSCA90201</Status_3>
                <Status_4>ElectronicShippingInfoReceivedMay312011</Status_4>
                <Status_5>ShipmentAcceptedMay3120114:25pmPALOALTOCA94303</Status_5>
            </StatusBreakdown>
            <StatusCode>D</StatusCode>
       </PICNumber>
    </StatusList>
</StatusResponse>
```

The value 9477707123456123456781 will parsed to the PicNumber key correctly but everything else below it is skipped.

Comment: When you ask a question, it's appropriate to include a sample of the code you've written to show you've made an attempt to solve the problem. It shouldn't be the entire program, just enough to replicate whatever problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First walk, before you run. Get the values you need, then build the hash:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StatusResponse>
    <AccountID>123</AccountID>
    <ErrorMsg />
    <Test>Y</Test>
    <StatusList>
        <PICNumber>
            9477707123456123456781
            <Status>Youritemwasdeliveredat10:09AMon08/06/2007inPALOALTOCA94301.</Status>
            <StatusBreakdown>
                <Status_1>ArrivalatPostOfficeJune02201110:11amNORTHHOLLYWOODCA91605</Status_1>
                <Status_2>ForwardExpiredJune0220116:59amNORTHHOLLYWOODCA</Status_2>
                <Status_3>ProcessedthroughSortFacilityJune0120114:53pmBELLGARDENSCA90201</Status_3>
                <Status_4>ElectronicShippingInfoReceivedMay312011</Status_4>
                <Status_5>ShipmentAcceptedMay3120114:25pmPALOALTOCA94303</Status_5>
            </StatusBreakdown>
            <StatusCode>D</StatusCode>
      </PICNumber>
    </StatusList>
</StatusResponse>
EOT

account_id = doc.at('AccountID').text

pic = doc.at('StatusList PICNumber')
pic_number = pic.child.text.strip
status_msg = pic.at('Status').text

status_breakdown_statuses = pic.search('StatusBreakdown *').map { |n|
  n.text
}

status_code = pic.at('StatusCode').text

hash = {
  :account_id  => account_id,
  :pic_num     => pic_number,
  :status_msg  => status_msg,
  :statuses    => status_breakdown_statuses,
  :status_code => status_code
}
```

In IRB that looks like:

```
{
     :account_id => "123",
        :pic_num => "9477707123456123456781",
       :status_m => "Youritemwasdeliveredat10:09AMon08/06/2007inPALOALTOCA94301.",
       :statuses => [
        [0] "ArrivalatPostOfficeJune02201110:11amNORTHHOLLYWOODCA91605",
        [1] "ForwardExpiredJune0220116:59amNORTHHOLLYWOODCA",
        [2] "ProcessedthroughSortFacilityJune0120114:53pmBELLGARDENSCA90201",
        [3] "ElectronicShippingInfoReceivedMay312011",
        [4] "ShipmentAcceptedMay3120114:25pmPALOALTOCA94303"
    ],
    :status_code => "D"
}
```

What you want isn't exactly clear, so this is more some example code to get sections of the XML. Depending on the XML received, and my needs, I might do it differently.

Comment: The code doesn't get  9477707123456123456781 value.  Its nil in the hash.

Comment: Could you change it to pic_number = pic.children.first.text .  That will make pic_num not nil.

Comment: No, because that's not the right command. `pic.child.text.strip` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the nokogiri gem. The read me is pretty straightforward.